# Django forms.ModelChoiceField (empty_label) NOT passing the (mark_safe) values

Tags: python, html, css, django, dom

I have a problem using the forms.py file, as I'm trying to customize the `empty_label` attribute of the `forms.ModelChoiceField` forms type.

My main target is to customize the placeholder by passing HTML and CSS using the `mark_safe` function.
However, when the page is rendered, the placeholder is rendered without the added HTML. The added HTML is present in the viewSource of the page but not the DOM.

```
class ModelX(forms.Form):
    Name = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        empty_label=mark_safe('<span style="font-style: italic; color:#6c757d;"> (Please Select a 
        name...) </span>'),
    )
```

Comment: This might be the browser "fixing" the HTML. Exactly how are your items rendered? As `<option>`s?

Comment: Yes, all of the items are rendered as `<option>`, the `empty_label` is rendered as `<option value selected >`